# Kafka 0.8.1 Async Producer in Scala - cannot detect Kafka cluster is down

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I have a very weird problem where I am implementing a Kafka Producer client in Scala, and everything works as normal when the Kafka cluster is up. That is, the Producer pushes data into Kafka properly.

However, if I set my producer to be 'async', the Kafka Producer client will correctly put data if a cluster is UP and working, but the Producer also pushes data into...the void... if the cluster is DOWN! That is, the Kafka Producer does not return an error if the cluster is down.

This is a concern to me because as the Producer finds data to push into Kafka, it deletes that source of data...so if the cluster ever goes down, the Producer will just destroy all the source data.

If the Producer is set into 'sync' mode however, the Producer does correctly fail after the default 3 retries, according to the property (I think message.send.max.retries ).

Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 1):

This is the documented behavior of the async producer. Use the sync-producer if you actually care if the messages made it to the broker.

Or, better yet (although not fully documented yet), use Kafka 0.8.2-beta with the new producer - this lets you send messages asynchronously yet examine a returned "future" object for status.